# HTC Desire C stopped working after factory reset

Tags: factory-reset, boot

I have a HTC Desire C. I performed a reset to factory settings. It went through the whole process, was shutting down to restart but it never restarted and now I can't even turn it on. I have pulled the battery, I've pulled the SD card... doesn't matter what I do I can't get it to turn on. Any ideas???? Can't even find the software for it to reinstall it. I plug into my computer it acknowledges that it is there but do have the software....ugh.

Answer (score 1):

> *If your phone is not starting anyway try performing hard reset using hardware buttons*

**Performing a factory reset using hardware buttons**

> Note: All your data will be lost.

*If you can’t turn HTC Desire 700 on or access settings, you can still perform a factory reset by using the hardware buttons on HTC Desire 700.*

*Important: The Fast boot option in Settings > Power must not be selected.*

1. Remove the battery, wait for a few seconds, then reinsert the battery.
2. Press and hold the VOLUME DOWN button, and then press and hold the POWER button.
3. Wait for the screen with the three Android images to appear, and then release the POWER and VOLUME DOWN buttons.
4. Press VOLUME DOWN to select FACTORY RESET, and then press the POWER button.

> If doing the above doesn't help you should reach your nearest htc service center